# What happens if plugin GUI is closed?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I'm developing a plugin for JMeter.

One of the operations is checking connection with our server once per 30 seconds. For this purpose I start separate thread in `checkConnection();` method and place this method to the constructor of Listener. I want to interrupt thread if user closes test-plan with my listener or removes listener from test-plan.

Please, give me a piece of advice, where to place `interrupt();` for this thread?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion your thread lifecycle should be part of listener lifecycle, so it seems to me it's a bad idea to do that in constructor.

Can't you do that within listener methods ?

Comment: I want to check connection to server every 30 seconds and display current status on GUI. For this purpose I've written simple method, that sends HTTP request. My problem is, that if I close test-plan(without closing JMeter), statusChecker remains working. And it is not good for me. So I search for place in code, where I can start statusChecker(when test-plan is opened) and stop it(when test-plan is closed). Currently, the only place that I've found - constructor.